# Error adding site in cloudflare

Tags: dns

Not sure if my question fits here (please consider flagging it if I violate guidelines).

I got the following error while adding a domain to Cloudflare:

```
Failed to lookup registrar and hosting information of multiadventure.com.np at this time. Please contact Cloudflare Support or try again later. (Code: 1110)
```

When checking https://register.com.np/whois-lookup, I get ns fine.

What can cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

There are two nameservers defined for multiadventure.com.np:

```
mtak@gen1:~$ dig -t ns multiadventure.com.np +short
ns2.numri.net.
ns1.numri.net.
```

They both don't respond to queries:

```
mtak@gen1:~$ dig multiadventure.com.np @ns1.numri.net.

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u11-Debian <<>> multiadventure.com.np @ns1.numri.net.
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
mtak@gen1:~$ dig multiadventure.com.np @ns2.numri.net 

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u11-Debian <<>> multiadventure.com.np @ns2.numri.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

It's probably a good idea to check with your registrar and either fix the NS entries or have them fix the nameservers.